# Error: The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare

I get the following error

> The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable

when attempting to compare two same tables that are located on the same server but different databases e.g.

```
select top 1 * 
from [test1].[dbo].[PaperType]

except

select top 1 * 
from [test2].[dbo].[PaperType]
```

Both tables contain the same columns and seem to match in terms of data type and length.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). Change your columns to  `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, and you should be fine - or don't select those `ntext` column (use `select (list-of-colums)` instead of `select *` - a recommended best practice always)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ntext type is incomparable but you can use conversion to get around this limitation. List the columns in the query explicitly and wrap ntext column with cast:

```
select top 1 
  col1
, col2
, cast (MyNtextColumn as nvarchar(max)) as col3
from [test1].[dbo].[PaperType]

except

select top 1
  col1
, col2
, cast (MyNtextColumn as nvarchar(max)) as col3
from [test2].[dbo].[PaperType]
```

Comment: The suggestion has worked. I was able to compare the data properly this time. Thank you ivanochkah